# Create Array with specific key in PHP

Tags: php

seems like i'm blind at the moment. I want to build an empty array(). but instead of getting "0" as array-key i want to have a specific string as the key... Just to make it clear:

```
$array = array();
```

gives me:

```
[0] => array {
}
```

but i want it like that:

```
["string"] => array {
}
```

...this really drives me crazy right now.

Thanks,Alex

Comment: Your code example is incomplete because an array itself has no "key"... only its elements do. `$array['key'] = 'value'` is the way to assign keys and values.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$array = array();
$array['string'] = "foo";  // this makes it so that $array['string'] = "foo"
$array[] = "bar";      // this makes it so that $array[0] = "bar"
$array[] = "barbar";   // this makes it so that $array[1] = "barbar"

print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [string] => foo
    [0] => bar
    [1] => barbar
)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Even if this was not the Solution for my Problem, your Post helped me to find it. Thanks!!! P.S. i really was BLIND

Answer (score 5):

You mean like this?

```
$array = array('string' => array());
```

You might want to refresh your [Array](http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) [knowledge](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.array.php).

Answer (score 1):

$array = array("string" => array())

?